# ItemsControl has space between items

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, itemscontrol

I have space between my items and I cant remove it. I have been Googling about ItemsControl all day and found nothing that works. It also didn't work with listbox. It even made it worse.

Anyone has an idea?

Here is my code:

```
                <ItemsControl BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type newsSubscriber:Item}">
                        <Border VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" BorderThickness="0">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="{Binding RepeatImagePath}"/>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <StackPanel Cursor="Hand" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <StackPanel.InputBindings>
                                    <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding GoToWebCommand}" />
                                </StackPanel.InputBindings>
                                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Height="{Binding hight}" Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                    <StackPanel.Background>
                                        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="{Binding RepeatImagePath}"/>
                                    </StackPanel.Background>
                                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Width="70" Text="{Binding time}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Language="he-il" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="300" Text="{Binding title}"/>
                                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="38">
                                        <Image Stretch="None" Source="{Binding ArrowImagePath}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

output pic:
[image: output]

Comment: Posting an image and pointing out the spaces could help.

Comment: added, see the little white between the items? its the website behind the program.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably Height="{Binding hight}" property set to some large value.

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            FlowDirection="RightToLeft" 
            Height="{Binding hight}" 
            Orientation="Horizontal"  
            HorizontalAlignment="Right">
```

Comment: i did it, the item got big but the space is the same. i dont think its inner item related more like Container related

Answer (score 0):

You where on the right track with the FrameworkElement.Margin Set the Value="-1". It creates a small overlap that removes the space.

```
<Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="-1"/>
```